# Python-сокеты: можно ли использовать не локальный ip?

Tags: python, сокет

Использую модуль socket, когда в команде socket.connect() использую локальный ip, то все работает но мой комп должен быть в одной сети с другим, чтобы все работало. Есть ли способ подключаться к другим машинам, которые находятся в других сетях? Вот код клиента, если нужен.

```
#client
import socket

sock =  socket.socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.1.172', 9090))
sock.send("Conection confirmed!".encode())
print("CONFIRMED")

while True:

    a=input("CLIENT: ")


    a=a.encode()
    sock.send(a)



sock.close()
```

Comment: Очевидно, просто пишите не локальный ip да и всё. Если не работает — значит на пути к другому компьютеру какой-то firewall или NAT не пропускает соединение; обращайтесь к тому системному администратору, который не пускает

Comment: зря минусуете. обход ната и всякое п2п - интересная тема

Comment: дополните вопрос пожалуйста - что именно не получилось, какое сообщение получили...

Comment: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it  подобная ошибка возникает когда использую ip отличный от локального. У меня она и раньше возникала когда использовал порт меньше 1024. Буду признателен если кто подскажет что можно вместо сокетов использовать для связи двух компьютеров.